# SMS Gateway SMSC/ESME TON/NPI

Tags: sms, sms-gateway, smpp, telecommunication

I'm developing an SMS Gateway and I was thinking about the features that I should implement in it. So I reviewed some SMS gateways (SMSNOW, SMS studio, and Ozeki) for examples.

I almost finished the implementation but I came across a feature in almost all SMS gateways which allows the user to specify TON/NPI for SMSC and ESME.

I understand that when the SMS gateway is preparing to send the sms using the SMPP protocol it would need to parse the sender/reciever number and based on that, specify TON/NPI. And I understand that it's great to allow you to override the defaults and specify your own TON/NPI.

What I don't understand is why all SMS gateways give you the option to specify your own TON/NPI for the SMS gateway when it acts as SMSC (when it receives SMS, not sending them).

What would the SMS gateway do with the specified TON/NPI when it recieves an smpp SMS?

Answer (score 5):

The full specification of an SMS source address involves 3 attributes:

- **TON**
- **NPI**
- The actual **Address**

---

#### TON = Type of Number.

This specifies whether the number is a full *International Number* (i.e. needs the `+` prefix), or a *National Number*, or even an *alphanumeric* sender (i.e. includes up to 11 characters of text instead of a numeric sender, quite useful for advertising).

#### NPI = Numbering Plan Indicator

This specifies which numbering standard the number is following. It could be the [*E.164*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E.164) standard *international* numbering, or the operator's *private* numbering (for premium rated services for instance).

#### The actual Address.

An SMSC would need the TON/NPI to know how to interpret the bytes stored in the ***Address***. If for example the TON is *alphanumeric* (5), it knows the bytes in the address need to be interpreted as characters and encoded accordingly, while if it is *International* (1), it would split each byte into 2, with each half byte representing a different digit for the sender.

---

You can refer to the [SMPP 3.4 specification](http://www.qtelecom.ru/wiki/_media/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8B:smpp34.pdf) Sections 5.2.5 and 5.2.6 for a full list of these TON/NPI possibilities. The specific SMS gateway you're using might restrict you from using some of them.

Answer (score 0):

**TON (Type of Number)**

If you wish to specify a special value for the TON, the available options are:

0: Unknown
1: International
2: National
3: Network Specific
4: Subscriber Number
5: Alphanumeric
6: Abbreviated

**NPI (Numbering Plan Identification)**

For NPI, the available options are:

```
Unknown = 0
ISDN/telephone numbering plan (E163/E164) = 1
Data numbering plan (X.121) = 3
Telex numbering plan (F.69) = 4
Land Mobile (E.212) =6
National numbering plan = 8
Private numbering plan = 9
ERMES numbering plan (ETSI DE/PS 3 01-3) = 10
Internet (IP) = 13
WAP Client Id (to be defined by WAP Forum) = 18
```

**TON and NPI Defaults**

**Short Code** (3 digits to 8 digits in length)
If the source code/address is a Short Code

```
TON = 3
NPI = 0
```

**Long Code** (10 digits to 15 digits in length, excludes the plus sign)

```
TON = 1
NPI = 1
```

**Alphanumeric**
If the source code/address is Alphanumeric (contains both letters and numbers or only letters)

```
TON = 5
NPI = 0
```